# Fedora UI Themes

Tags: fedora, gnome, theme

I have recently installed fedora 23. Then I decided to change the UI theme.I have installed gnome-tweak-tool, installed User Theme Extention. Also I see that there are many themes in /usr/share/themes folder. Problem is that, I can't install those themes. They neither appear in the tweak-tool nor can be set by gsettings command. How could I solve that problem?